# Filtering twitter data according to their creation date

Tags: r

I am working on tweets that I **scraped** as json file from twitter. I convert it to data frame. I have `text` and `created_at` columns. I want to filter my data according to their creating date. To **scrape** the 1 week tweet, I wrote the following code:

`firstweek <-filter(alldataframe, 2019-03-07 21:56:08 >= created_at >=2019-03-07 21:56:08 )`
(in the data, creation times are as in above, first date and then time)

So that code gave me `Error: unexpected numeric constant in "firstweek <-filter(alldataframe, 2019-03-07 21"`  error.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow.  Look more closely at the syntax for `dplyr::filter()` and for comparing dates.  There are several errors.

Comment: I found how it should be: `first <-filter(alldataframe, "2019-03-07 21:56:08 " < created_at &  created_at < "2019-03-14 22:00:00" )`

Comment: Cool.  I was wondering about the start & stop dates being the same.